# Nav2 build error on Dockerfile for Jetson Nano

Tags: docker, nav2

I'm working on build Nav2 from source on a Dockerfile for the Jetson Nano. The official ubuntu distro is ubuntu 18.04, so I'm using `https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-containers` as a base image.
My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM dustynv/ros:humble-ros-base-l4t-r32.7.1

RUN mkdir -p /root/nav2_ws/src
WORKDIR /root/nav2_ws

ENV ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/humble/install

# ROS fundamentals
RUN apt-mark hold '*opencv*' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt autoremove -y \
    && rosinstall_generator --deps --exclude RPP --rosdistro humble navigation2 > ros2.humble.nav2.rosinstall \
    && vcs import src/ < ros2.humble.nav2.rosinstall \
    && . /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/install/setup.sh \
    && rosdep fix-permissions \
    && rosdep update \
    && rosdep install -y --ignore-src --from-paths src --rosdistro humble --skip-keys "xsimd" --skip-keys "ignition-cmake2" --skip-keys "ignition-math6"

RUN echo "Fixing client.hpp file" \
    && sed -i "s|return value|return std::move(value) |g" /opt/ros/humble/install/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/client.hpp \
    && echo "client.hpp fixed"  \
    && echo "Building..." \
    && . /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/install/setup.sh \
    && colcon build --symlink-install --base-paths src --event-handlers console_direct+ &> results.txt

# ENV RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
# COPY ros_entrypoint.sh /
# ENTRYPOINT ["/ros_entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bash"]
```

After an hour or so the build proces fail. I have a file with the complete build output, but the important part is, I think, this one:

```
[Processing: nav2_behavior_tree, nav2_costmap_2d, ompl, rviz_ogre_vendor]
[ 28%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/layers.dir/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object src/ompl/CMakeFiles/ompl.dir/multilevel/datastructures/projections/src/None.cpp.o
[ 43%] Linking CXX shared library libnav2_planner_selector_bt_node.so
[ 39%] Building CXX object OgreMain/CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/src/OgreLog.cpp.o
[ 43%] Built target nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/nav2_controller_selector_bt_node.dir/plugins/action/controller_selector_node.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object src/ompl/CMakeFiles/ompl.dir/multilevel/datastructures/projections/src/RNSO2_RN.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:40,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/layer.hpp:40,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise_layer.hpp:18,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp:15:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair<nav2_costmap_2d::Image<short unsigned int>, short unsigned int>’:
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image_processing.hpp:989:56:   required from ‘void nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = short unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]’
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image_processing.hpp:972:37:   required from ‘bool nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::tryRemoveGroupsWithLabelType(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, size_t, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, const IsBg&, bool) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = short unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]’
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image_processing.hpp:936:59:   required from ‘void nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsPickLabelType(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]’
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image_processing.hpp:908:7:   required from ‘void nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]’
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp:156:56:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:303:17: error: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = nav2_costmap_2d::Image<short unsigned int>; _T2 = short unsigned int]’ declared to take const reference, but implicit declaration would take non-const
       constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
                 ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair<nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned int>, unsigned int>’:
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image_processing.hpp:989:56:   required from ‘void nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]’
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image_processing.hpp:972:37:   required from ‘bool nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::tryRemoveGroupsWithLabelType(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, size_t, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, const IsBg&, bool) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]’
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image_processing.hpp:950:49:   required from ‘void nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsPickLabelType(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]’
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image_processing.hpp:908:7:   required from ‘void nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]’
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp:156:56:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:303:17: error: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned int>; _T2 = unsigned int]’ declared to take const reference, but implicit declaration would take non-const
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/functional:64:0,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/install/include/tf2_ros/tf2_ros/async_buffer_interface.h:33,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/install/include/tf2_ros/tf2_ros/buffer.h:41,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/layer.hpp:44,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise_layer.hpp:18,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp:15:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:4295:5: error: ‘_OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long unsigned int*, std::vector<long unsigned int> >; _OIter = std::_Bit_iterator; _UnaryOperation = nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = short unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(size_t)>]’, declared using local type ‘nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = short unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(size_t)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
     transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
     ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image_processing.hpp:18:0,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise_layer.hpp:19,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp:15:
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image.hpp:184:6: error: ‘void nav2_costmap_2d::Image<T>::convert(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<TargetElement>&, Converter&&) const [with TargetElement = unsigned char; Converter = nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = short unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(short unsigned int, uint8_t&)>; T = short unsigned int]’, declared using local type ‘nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = short unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(short unsigned int, uint8_t&)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
 void Image<T>::convert(Image<TargetElement> & target, Converter && converter) const
      ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/functional:64:0,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/install/include/tf2_ros/tf2_ros/async_buffer_interface.h:33,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/install/include/tf2_ros/tf2_ros/buffer.h:41,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/layer.hpp:44,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise_layer.hpp:18,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp:15:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:4295:5: error: ‘_OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long unsigned int*, std::vector<long unsigned int> >; _OIter = std::_Bit_iterator; _UnaryOperation = nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(size_t)>]’, declared using local type ‘nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(size_t)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
     transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
     ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image_processing.hpp:18:0,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise_layer.hpp:19,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp:15:
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image.hpp:184:6: error: ‘void nav2_costmap_2d::Image<T>::convert(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<TargetElement>&, Converter&&) const [with TargetElement = unsigned char; Converter = nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(unsigned int, uint8_t&)>; T = unsigned int]’, declared using local type ‘nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(unsigned int, uint8_t&)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
 void Image<T>::convert(Image<TargetElement> & target, Converter && converter) const
      ^~~~~~~~
[ 48%] Building CXX object src/ompl/CMakeFiles/ompl.dir/multilevel/datastructures/projections/src/RN_RM.cpp.o
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image.hpp:184:6: error: ‘void nav2_costmap_2d::Image<T>::convert(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<TargetElement>&, Converter&&) const [with TargetElement = unsigned char; Converter = nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>]::<lambda(unsigned int, uint8_t&)>; T = unsigned int]’ used but never defined [-Werror]
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/functional:64:0,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/install/include/tf2_ros/tf2_ros/async_buffer_interface.h:33,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/install/include/tf2_ros/tf2_ros/buffer.h:41,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/layer.hpp:44,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise_layer.hpp:18,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp:15:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:4295:5: error: ‘_OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long unsigned int*, std::vector<long unsigned int> >; _OIter = std::_Bit_iterator; _UnaryOperation = nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>]::<lambda(size_t)>]’ used but never defined [-Werror]
     transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
     ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image_processing.hpp:18:0,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise_layer.hpp:19,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp:15:
/root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise/image.hpp:184:6: error: ‘void nav2_costmap_2d::Image<T>::convert(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<TargetElement>&, Converter&&) const [with TargetElement = unsigned char; Converter = nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = short unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>]::<lambda(short unsigned int, uint8_t&)>; T = short unsigned int]’ used but never defined [-Werror]
 void Image<T>::convert(Image<TargetElement> & target, Converter && converter) const
      ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/functional:64:0,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/install/include/tf2_ros/tf2_ros/async_buffer_interface.h:33,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/install/include/tf2_ros/tf2_ros/buffer.h:41,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/layer.hpp:44,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/include/nav2_costmap_2d/denoise_layer.hpp:18,
                 from /root/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp:15:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:4295:5: error: ‘_OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long unsigned int*, std::vector<long unsigned int> >; _OIter = std::_Bit_iterator; _UnaryOperation = nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::GroupsRemover::removeGroupsImpl(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&, nav2_costmap_2d::MemoryBuffer&, nav2_costmap_2d::imgproc_impl::EquivalenceLabelTrees<Label>&, size_t, const IsBg&) const [with nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType connectivity = (nav2_costmap_2d::ConnectivityType)4; Label = short unsigned int; IsBg = nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer::removeGroups(nav2_costmap_2d::Image<unsigned char>&) const::<lambda(uint8_t)>]::<lambda(size_t)>]’ used but never defined [-Werror]
     transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
     ^~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
CMakeFiles/layers.dir/build.make:159: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/layers.dir/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/layers.dir/plugins/denoise_layer.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:294: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/layers.dir/all' failed
Makefile:145: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/layers.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
--- stderr: nav2_costmap_2d
```

Searching on the web I found some similar error (I'm a noobe on C++) and thought that could be C++ version in the system. But I'm not sure.